# How can I create a type for an object, where the keys are read-only and dynamic, but the values are a fixed type?

Tags: typescript

I have an object called carLot that looks like this

```typescript
interface Car {
  model: string;
  year: number;
}

const carLot: Record<string, Car> = {
  oldCar: {
    model: "acura",
    year: 1998,
  },
  otherCar: {
    model: "Mitsubishi",
    year: 1995,
  }
}
```

I want to make all the keys read-only, that way when the object is read elsewhere, users can only access the properties that exist in the object. I'm well aware that I could declare the keys separately as their own type if I do something like

```typescript
type carKeys = "oldCar" | "otherCar"

// and then do
const carLot: Record<carKeys, Car> {
  ...
}
```

However I expect that my object will have hundreds or even up to a thousand keys, and I do not want to declare them one by one. I'd also like to keep the type declaration in the object itself. That way new cars added by users are also type-checked. Is there a clean way to declare this type?

Comment: ① I'm confused by the two statements "users can only access the properties that exist in the object" and " new cars added by users are also type-checked"; are the users only reading the object or are they adding things to the object? What's the desired behavior, can you demonstrate it? ② Could you [edit] to fix the typos in your example code? Try it in an IDE to see them. ③Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDAe6m) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I apologize, to clarify, users will add to the original object by writing more properties to the code itself, not at runtime. Your example works perfectly it covers exactly the scenarios I was looking for. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like the compiler to *infer* the type of `carLot` to have known keys with [`readonly` properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) of type `Car`.  Hey, maybe even of type `Readonly<Car>` using [the `Readonly` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype) to make sure the properties of `Car` are themselves `readonly`. I'm not sure if you actually care about `readonly` to be honest.

The main thing is: instead of having to specify the keys twice, once in the type and once int he object literal value, you want to just write them in the object literal and have them inferred.

Sometimes you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to accomplish this, but when I tried it made the properties non-`readonly` no matter what.  Oh well.  Instead you can use the more general method of writing a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function that just returns its input but guides inference.  In this case it looks like:

```
const asCarLot = <K extends string>(
  r: { readonly [P in K]: Readonly<Car> }
) => r;
```

Now instead of `const carLot: SomeCarLotType = {⋯}`, you write `const carLot = asCarLot({⋯})`.  Like so:

```
const carLot = asCarLot({
  oldCar: {
    model: "acura",
    year: 1998,
  },
  otherCar: {
    model: "Mitsubishi",
    year: 1995,
  }
});

/* const carLot: {
    readonly oldCar: Readonly<Car>;
    readonly otherCar: Readonly<Car>;
} */
```

You can see that `carLot` has been inferred to be of the desired type.  If you edit the object literal to add new entries, the type of `carLot` will change accordingly:

```
const carLot = asCarLot({
  oldCar: {
    model: "acura",
    year: 1998,
  },
  otherCar: {
    model: "Mitsubishi",
    year: 1995,
  },
  yetAnother: {
    model: "Yugo", 
    year: 1994
  }
});

/* const carLot: {
    readonly oldCar: Readonly<Car>;
    readonly otherCar: Readonly<Car>;
    readonly yetAnother: Readonly<Car>;
} */
```

If you edit the object literal to set a value to a non-`Car`-compatible type, it will issue an error accordingly:

```
const carLot = asCarLot({
  oldCar: {
    model: "acura",
    year: "nineteen ninety eight", // error
  },
  otherCar: {
    model: "Mitsubishi",
    year: 1995,
    color: "blue", // error
  }
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-7gqLA+mnFFRdFQTHdROorz60HwqEYmGw3PJrW6-XhIuZ7MSHF4vAZd6vKkAZnJBSpNNKdLFS2Nq3Z7UV3L6jRAoAgkAgIC907AXggwGYMzAVpthigUBIUHVVwLDMH9VWGy2Oz2B05TJOKouY5klD3qyElH4EE3tugu-3EzD9xAA)